# Get correct offset using timezoneoffse table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timezone

I am trying to figure out the offset that should be applied to a meeting with start and end date time.

Timezone table below stores the utc offset in minutes and when the utc offset became active.

```
Timezone Table
TimezoneCode        StartDate                EndDate            UtcOffSetInMinute
Antarctica/Casey    2020-04-05 02:00:00     2020-09-26 02:00:00 720
Antarctica/Casey    2020-09-27 05:00:00     2020-05-03 05:00:00 780
```

Meeting table which stores all the meetings

```
Meeting Table
|Id  | StartDateTime       | EndDateTime
+----+---------------------+----------------------
|1   | 2020-04-06 23:00:00 | 2020-09-26 05:00:00
|2   | 2020-10-21 10:00:00 | 2020-10-21 11:00:00
```

Using the above timezone table I am struggling to figure local time of meeting.
How can we join the timezone table with meeting table and get the utcoffset for meeting based on date range?

```
Expected output
|Id  | StartDateTime       | EndDateTime         | OffsetInMins
+----+---------------------+----------------------
|1   | 2020-04-06 23:00:00 | 2020-09-26 05:00:00 | 720
|2   | 2020-09-27 23:00:00 | 2020-09-29 05:00:00 | 780
```

Comment: How do you know the timezone of a meeting?  It doesn't seem to be stored in the data you have shown.  Also, timezone changes (for daylight saving time) do not necessarily occur at midnight, so your offset table is inaccurate.  And where does row "2" come from?  And why do the ids change?

Comment: If you are using SQL 2016+ or Azure SQL Database, I suggest you leverage datetimeoffset type and T-SQL timezone features rather than roll you own table.

Comment: -Gordan Linoff 1: meeting time is stored in utc. 2: I have added datetime to timezone table. 2: do you mean in meeting table? if so these are ids of each meeting I am showing two meetings in meeting table. Also user viewing the meeting could be in any timezone but in the system we store their tz timezone code. Using the timeozone table i can figoure out which offset to use but having trouble with the query. -Dan Guzman I can't use datetimeOffset because meeting can be viewed in multiple timezones. If meeting is created in utc +6 this won't work if user is in utc +10.

Comment: I fixed the expected output it contained 3 rows should only be 2